# magento - error after changing catalogsearch.xml

Tags: xml, magento, simplexml, php

Was attempting to remove the Search Terms and Advanced Search from the footer links.
I am now getting the following message:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 103: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in /home/viviscal/domains/viviscal.ca/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 294

When I changed the file back, I'm still getting this message.
Anyone know what might be causing it?

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 1):

sorry.. found a solution...
for some reason my ftp client was copying the code and appending it to the end of the file each time i updated it.. 
I deleted the duplications, and this resolved my error.

Thanks,
Fiona